# Error Executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When i tried to execute this stored procedure it give me is not a valid identifier error can anyone help me?

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[AddLogtrail]
    @cmodule varchar(100),   
    @caudittype varchar(15),     
    @ctable varchar(100),    
    @cfield varchar(100),    
    @cfieldtype varchar(100),   
    @coriginalval varchar(100),      
    @cnewval    varchar(100),    
    @cuser varchar(100),     
    @creason varchar(100)     AS    

    DECLARE @SQL  varchar (400)     
    set  @SQL = 'Insert into AudittrailLog (ddatetime,cmodulename,caudittype,ctablename,cfieldname,cfieldtype,coriginalval,cnewval,cuser,creason) values ' + 
    '(convert(datetime,GETDATE(),105),'+@cmodule+','+@caudittype+','+@ctable+','+@cfield+','+@cfieldtype+','+@coriginalval+','+@cnewval+','+@cuser+','+@creason+')';
    PRINT @SQL
    Exec @SQL
```

Comment: When you PRINT @SQL, you get the whole query or is it truncated?

Comment: i get the whole query... Insert into AudittrailLog (
    ddatetime
      ,cmodulename
      ,caudittype
      ,ctablename
      ,cfieldname
      ,cfieldtype
      ,coriginalval
      ,cnewval
      ,cuser
      ,creason) values (convert(datetime,GETDATE(),105),test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add additional quotes for varchar values

```
set  @SQL = 'Insert into AudittrailLog (ddatetime,cmodulename,caudittype,ctablename,cfieldname,cfieldtype,coriginalval,cnewval,cuser,creason) values ' + 
    '(convert(datetime,GETDATE(),105),'''+@cmodule+''','''+@caudittype+''','''+@ctable+''','''+@cfield+''','''+@cfieldtype+''','''+@coriginalval+''','''+@cnewval+''','''+@cuser+''','''+@creason+''')';
```

When printed it should display like this.

```
Insert into AudittrailLog ( ddatetime ,cmodulename ,caudittype ,ctablename ,cfieldname ,cfieldtype ,coriginalval ,cnewval ,cuser ,creason) values (convert(datetime,GETDATE(),105),'test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test')
```

Also execute it like below

```
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: when i call the stored procedure it still gives me an is not a valid identifier but when i copy the print query.. it run..

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each `varchar` in '':

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[AddLogtrail]
    @cmodule varchar(100),   
    @caudittype varchar(15),     
    @ctable varchar(100),    
    @cfield varchar(100),    
    @cfieldtype varchar(100),   
    @coriginalval varchar(100),      
    @cnewval    varchar(100),    
    @cuser varchar(100),     
    @creason varchar(100)     AS    

    DECLARE @SQL  varchar (400)     
    set  @SQL = 'Insert into AudittrailLog (ddatetime,cmodulename,caudittype,ctablename,cfieldname,cfieldtype,coriginalval,cnewval,cuser,creason) values ' + 
    '(convert(datetime,GETDATE(),105),'''+@cmodule+''','''+@caudittype+''','''+@ctable+''','''+@cfield+''','''+@cfieldtype+''','''+@coriginalval+''','''+@cnewval+''','''+@cuser+''','''+@creason+''')';
    PRINT @SQL
    Exec @SQL
```

I hope I didn't miss any of ''.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question just a sample or your actual procedure?

Because there's no reason to use dynamic SQL for this procedure. Your query is static. It's a simple inset where all fields are known. Why aren't you just using an INSERT statement directly?